# Generate .prettierrc file

Tags: javascript, json, visual-studio-code, format, prettier

I found this file .prettierrc inside a project.
I would like to know how to generate it from visual studio code.
Or I just create a new file named .prettierrc?

I tried to find something on internet but i am still confused

Comment: It's a text file with a specific name. https://prettier.io/docs/en/configuration.html

Answer (score 16):

Here is the [documentation](https://prettier.io/docs/en/install.html).

If you go to the `package.json` file in your project, you probably will see that `prettier` is listed on the `devDependencies`.

As you can see in the documentation, you'll have to install it within your node project with:

```
npm install --save-dev --save-exact prettier
```

and then create the file manually with:

```
echo {}> .prettierrc.json
```

After that, you just need to configure it with your preferences. Check this [examples](https://prettier.io/docs/en/configuration.html).

Keep in mind that one common usage of `prettier`, is using it integrated it with linters. Check this [documentation](https://prettier.io/docs/en/precommit.html) as well.

Answer (score 0):

in terminal type

```
npm install prettier
```

then type

```
type nul > .prettier
```

to create its configuration file
if it doesn't work just remove the space between > and .